# Why Jackson Streaming API is slow?

Tags: java, jackson, java-11, jmh, jackson-modules

According to Jackson Streaming API documentation:

> If you explicitly rewrite all the conversions to use the Streaming API instead of data binding, you may be able to increase throughput by 30-40%; and this without any changes to actual JSON produced.

read full: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation:-Jackson-Performance

But, based on my benchmark, throughput improved by 15-20% in the best cases, and for a writing complex object even decreased by ~23%.

Am I doing something wrong? Why write operation for a complex object with streaming api is slower than is using ObjectMapper that work on top of streaming api?

It's quite interesting that Jackson Streaming performance writes degradation is more significant for java11/12 (~2% compare to ~24% for java 11/12).

**Configuration:**

- 8 CPU
- 64 GB RAM
- OS version 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24

**JMH Throughput Results:**

- Warmup: 10 iterations, 10 s each
- Measurement: 10 iterations, 10 s each
- Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
- VM options: -XX:+UseG1GC -server -Xmx4096m -Xms4096m
- Units: ops/s

**Complex Object**

[image: Big Object]
*json object size ~ 52KB*

**Plain Object**

[image: Tiny Objet]
*json object size ~ 72B*

**Structure:**

```java
// Plain object 
public class Sport{
    Long id;
    String name;
}

// Complex object 
public class Event {
    Long id;
    Long sportId;
    String name;
    Date startTime;
    boolean inRunning;
    boolean allowLiveBetting;
    List<Market> markets;
    List<EventParticipant> eventParticipants;
}

public class Market {
    Long id;
    Long eventId;
    String name;
    boolean inRunning;
    boolean allowLiveBetting;
    Double value;
    Integer winners;
    List<Runner> runners;
}

public class Runner {
    Long id;
    Long eventId;
    Long marketId;
    Long eventParticipantId;
    String name;
    boolean withdrawn;
    Double value;
}

public class EventParticipant{
    Long id;
    Long eventId;
    String participantName;
    String jockeyName;
    String trainerName;
    Integer number;
}
```

**Code**

```java
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void complexJacksonStreamWrite(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole blackhole) throws IOException {
        Event event = plan.getBigObjects();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (JsonGenerator generator =
                plan.getFactory().createGenerator(
                        outputStream, JsonEncoding.UTF8)) {
            generator.writeStartObject();
            generator.writeNumberField("id", event.getId());
            // populate rest attributes
            generator.writeFieldName("eventParticipants");
            generator.writeStartArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getEventParticipants().size(); i++) {
                EventParticipant eventParticipant = event.getEventParticipants().get(i);
                generator.writeStartObject();
                generator.writeNumberField("id", eventParticipant.getId());
                // populate rest attributes 
                generator.writeEndObject();
            }
            generator.writeEndArray();
            generator.writeEndObject();
        }
        blackhole.consume(outputStream);
    }
```

**How to run**

Java 8

> docker run -it volkodav/java-jackson-benchmark:java8

Java 11

> docker run -it volkodav/java-jackson-benchmark:java11

Java 12

> docker run -it volkodav/java-jackson-benchmark:java12

**Source code:**

https://github.com/volkodavs/jackson-benchmark

---

**UPDATE**

After comment @Jom Vernee, who suggests set the size for ByteArrayOutputStream - performance for Jackson Streaming Writes improved by ~10%.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(60_000);
```

**Complex**

[image: complex]

**Plain**

[image: plain]

Comment: Have you tried to pre-size the output stream? Given the difference in allocation pressure of the 2 methods, I'm guessing there is a bunch of re-allocation of the internal buffer being done. The initial size is just 32 bytes, which is then doubled when running out, but the internal buffer has to be copied in that case.

Comment: Yeah, you have a very valid point! I have applied your suggestion, performance improved for ~10%, but it's still slower than ObjectMapper ;(